# Sound Icon is missing - Vista Home Basic

Tags: windows-vista, audio, taskbar, icons

In my Vista Home Basic (laptop) today suddenly I noticed that sound icon is missing from the task bar.

**UPDATE**
It works from another login on the same laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've to go to the task bar properties every time and check volume option.

Comment: I've installed windows 7 now. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a random bug which still occurs in Windows 7, fixed by rebooting your system.

Comment: Naah!!! I'm into this problem from many days. It works in another login on the same laptop. I've shut and boot the system so many times after that.

Comment: I guess it has been hidden by accident under the small arrow to the left, you can either drag the icon back out of it or you can do the following: Right click on the `clock`, click `customize notificatino icons`, and click `show icon and notifications` for Sound. Does that work?